# How can I work with both scripts waypoints and teleporting together and how to make the teleporting to work better?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the Waypoints script the script is attached to a character. 
The character is waiting 10 seconds before he get into Walk state and start move between waypoints.
In the last waypoint the character is get into Idle state.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class Waypoints : UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> waypoints = new List<GameObject>();
    public Animator _animator;
    public int waitTimeBeforeGo;
    public int num = 0;
    public float minDist;
    public float speed;
    public bool rand = false;
    public bool go = true;
    public bool loop = false;
    public bool waitTime = false;
    public float smoothRotation;
    public bool inIdle = false;

    private bool lastPoint = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float dist = Vector3.Distance(gameObject.transform.position, waypoints[num].transform.position);

        if (waitTime == true)
        {
            StartCoroutine(WaitBeforeGo());
        }
        else
        {
            if (go)
            {
                _animator.SetBool("Walk", true);

                if (dist > minDist && lastPoint == false)
                {
                    Move();
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!rand)
                    {
                        if (num + 1 == waypoints.Count)
                        {
                            if (loop == true)
                            {
                                num = 0;
                            }

                            lastPoint = true;
                            _animator.SetBool("Idle", true);
                            inIdle = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            num++;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        num = Random.Range(0, waypoints.Count);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void Move()
    {
        Quaternion lookOnLook =
 Quaternion.LookRotation(waypoints[num].transform.position - transform.position);

        transform.rotation =
        Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, lookOnLook, Time.deltaTime * smoothRotation);

        gameObject.transform.position += gameObject.transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    IEnumerator WaitBeforeGo()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTimeBeforeGo);

        waitTime = false;
    }
}
```

And now I have also a Teleporting script that is attached to a teleporting object.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class Teleporting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> teleporters = new List<GameObject>();
    public GameObject objectToTeleportMaterial;
    public Waypoints waypoints;
    public float fadeDuration = 5;
    public float fadeInTargetOpacity = 0;
    public float fadeOutTargetOpacity = 1;

    private List<Vector3> teleportersPositions = new List<Vector3>();
    private bool teleported = false;
    private Material material;
    private GameObject myother;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.name == "vanguard_t_choonyung@T-Pose (1)")
        {
            teleported = false;
            myother = other.gameObject;
            material = objectToTeleportMaterial.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
            Teleport(material, fadeInTargetOpacity, fadeDuration);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(waypoints.inIdle == true)
        {   
            material.ToTransparentMode();
        }

        if (teleported == true)
        {
            myother.transform.position = teleporters[1].transform.position;
            Teleport(material, fadeOutTargetOpacity, fadeDuration);
            material.ToOpaqueMode();
            teleported = false;
        }
    }

    private void Teleport(Material material, float fadeTargetOpacity, float fadeDuration)
    {
        StartCoroutine(FadeTo(material, fadeTargetOpacity, fadeDuration));
    }

    // Define an enumerator to perform our fading.
    // Pass it the material to fade, the opacity to fade to (0 = transparent, 1 = opaque),
    // and the number of seconds to fade over.
    IEnumerator FadeTo(Material material, float targetOpacity, float duration)
    {

        // Cache the current color of the material, and its initiql opacity.
        Color color = material.color;
        float startOpacity = color.a;

        // Track how many seconds we've been fading.
        float t = 0;

        while (t < duration)
        {
            // Step the fade forward one frame.
            t += Time.deltaTime;
            // Turn the time into an interpolation factor between 0 and 1.
            float blend = Mathf.Clamp01(t / duration);

            // Blend to the corresponding opacity between start & target.
            color.a = Mathf.Lerp(startOpacity, targetOpacity, blend);

            // Apply the resulting color to the material.
            material.color = color;

            // Wait one frame, and repeat.
            yield return null;
        }

        if (targetOpacity == 1)
        {

        }

        if (targetOpacity == 0)
        {
            teleported = true;
        }
    }
}
```

With this script I have some problems.

- The character change to transparent mode in the material settins when start teleporting but after he teleported to the new position in the new position he never change back to the Opaque Mode in the material settings.
- On the new position when the character start to fade in back for a millisecond the character show like in Opaque Mode but then he is gone and then start to fade in in the second teleporter but never change to Opaque Mode.

This class is a helper class for changing the material modes between Transparent and Opaque :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public static class MaterialExtensions
{
    public static void ToOpaqueMode(this Material material)
    {
        material.SetOverrideTag("RenderType", "");
        material.SetInt("_SrcBlend", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.One);
        material.SetInt("_DstBlend", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.Zero);
        material.SetInt("_ZWrite", 1);
        material.DisableKeyword("_ALPHATEST_ON");
        material.DisableKeyword("_ALPHABLEND_ON");
        material.DisableKeyword("_ALPHAPREMULTIPLY_ON");
        material.renderQueue = -1;
    }

    public static void ToTransparentMode(this Material material)
    {
        material.SetOverrideTag("RenderType", "Transparent");
        material.SetInt("_SrcBlend", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.SrcAlpha);
        material.SetInt("_DstBlend", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.OneMinusSrcAlpha);
        material.SetInt("_ZWrite", 0);
        material.DisableKeyword("_ALPHATEST_ON");
        material.EnableKeyword("_ALPHABLEND_ON");
        material.DisableKeyword("_ALPHAPREMULTIPLY_ON");
        material.renderQueue = (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.RenderQueue.Transparent;
    }
}
```

What I want to do :

- The character walk between the waypoints. When the character get to the last waypoint and get into the idle state wait 1-2 seconds before starting the teleporting.
- When starting the teleporting the character should change to transparent mode and slowly fade out and change position.
- In the new position the character should fade in slowly and then change slowly back to the Opaque Mode.
- The character should start moving between new waypoints in his new position after teleported faded in and after changed back to Opaque Mode.

How can I make the character to wait 1-2 seconds in idle state before start teleporting ?

How can I make the character on his new position after faded in and after change to Opaque Mode to start moving between new waypoints ? I added waypoints in his new position.

How can I fix the problems with the teleporting script ? The teleporting it self is still not smooth. The first time the fade out part is fine but the fade in in the new position is not working good.

Some screenshot about the Transparent and Opaque modes.

The first screenshot showing the alpha on Transparent mode when alpha value is set to 255:

Even if the alpha value is 255 on Transparent mode the character is still looks transparent.

[Transparent alpha color is set to 255](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDSRA.jpg)

The second screenshot also Transparent this time al[ha is set to 0 :

[Transparent mode alpha is set to 0 but still some of the character still show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qN28.jpg)

I see now that even on Transparent when alpha is 0 you can see a bit yet of the character he is not vanished a bit of him still left.

Now a screenshot of the Opaque mode one screenshot since nothing change if alpha is 0 or 255 on Opaque mode:

[Opaque mode alpha is at 255](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDUAL.jpg)

So what have I learned from this screenshots and mode so far :

1. Transparent mode when alpha is set to 0 does not make the character to completely gone. It looks like from a bit far distance but if you looks close you see a bit of the character still left.
2. Transparent mode when alpha is set to 255 the character is not filled completely he still looks transparent.
3. Opaque mode when alpha is set to 0 or 255 same result the character is filled like he is in the original.

All this tests I did on the Standard shader.

Answer (score 0):

**Transparency issues**

Do you use a custom shader? Because I think an easier solution would be to use a material with a standard shader, then you can set the [Rendering Mode](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StandardShaderMaterialParameterRenderingMode.html). Then you don't have to deal with setting properties in the shader. There is a mode specifically for fading in and out (`BlendMode.Fade`)

I believe it wont really make a difference (maybe a bit performance wise but not much) if you leave the material to be a material capable of transparency, it will still be opaque with an alpha of one so visually it wouldn't be a difference.

If you still want to switch between transparent and opaque rendering modes or use your extension methods, I would suggest putting the switch to opaque mode when the coroutine is finished:

```cs
if(targetOpacity == 1f) { material.ToOpaqueMode(); }
```

and not immediately after starting the coroutine.

**Teleporting after x seconds**

You could just write another coroutine / function that calls a function after x seconds

*using only a coroutine*

```cs
private IEnumerator TeleportAfter(float time, etc...) {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    Teleport(...);
}
```

*using a coroutine and a wrapper function* (easier to call / doesn't need StartCoroutine)*

```cs
private IEnumerator TeleportAfter(float time, etc...) {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    Teleport(...);
}

private void TeleportAfterSeconds(float time, etc...) {
    StartCoroutine(TeleportAfter(time, etc...));
}
```

Comment: I tried it before using only Transparent mode. The problem is when in transparent if the value is 1 the character is still transparent. and I want it to be completely not transparent(opaque).

Comment: I will add to my question some screenshots to show it.

Comment: Interesting stuff I learned now or discovered about the Transparent and the Opaque modes more on the Transparent mode.

Comment: when you set the mode to transparent, things like specular highlights and reflections *wont* disappear. For that you need to use the mode Fade. Do you also have a screenshot of the texture inspector (sprite settings, etc.) because maybe the texture has an alpha channel with different values than one and in the shader the color gets multiplied with the texture, so that might cause the character to not be completely opaque.